# How to change the background colour for MaterialCardView using the style.xml file?

Tags: android, android-theme

I want to change the background colour for MaterialCardView using the style.xml file. It would really help with implementing "Dark mode"in my Android app.

I have tried dynamically doing but would prefer this done using the theme.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Create your custom style for MaterialCardView that extends Widget.MaterialComponents.CardView:

```
<style name="YourCardView" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.CardView">
    <item name="cardBackgroundColor">@color/your_color</item>
</style>
```

Then you can set this style manually to your single MaterialCardView in xml layout:

```
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="@style/YourCardView">
        <!-- card content -->
</com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

Or you can set the style for all MaterialCardViews within your custom theme (that extends a theme from MaterialComponents):

```
<style name="YourTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="materialCardViewStyle">@style/YourCardView</item>
</style>
```

Comment: What about changing the color of the clicking on it?

Answer (score 12):

Actually, I got it working by adding the attribute

```
app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorAccent"
```

Of course, you have to define the app namespace, that goes by the following:

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

Answer (score 5):

`Widget.MaterialComponents.CardView` can be styled just alike any other component:

```
<style name="CustomCardView" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.CardView">
    <item name="cardBackgroundColor">?attr/colorSurface</item>
</style>
```

Changing `colorSurface`, which defaults to `#FFFFFF`, might be rather effective for a dark theme.

see the [documentation](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/theming/Color.md), which also explains how to apply it to all instances.